# CSC : warning RSG002: TargetPath not specified for additional file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, csc

The command `dotnet build` for a razor page app with [.net-6.0](/questions/tagged/.net-6.0) throws lots of warnings like

```
CSC : warning RSG002: TargetPath not specified for additional file: 
      C:\dev\Foo\Foo\Pages\Admin\Administration\Users\Delete.cshtml. 
      [C:\dev\Foo\Foo\Foo.csproj]   

    .... lots of other files with the same warning
```

This is my build engine

```
C:\dev\Foo\Foo>dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.0.0+c9eb9dd64 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.   

  Determining projects to restore...
```

#### Questions

1. Do all developers need to have the same local file structure?
2. For example if Sheldon uses `C:\dev\foo` are Raj and Howard not allowed to use `d:\mycode\bar\foo`?
3. How do i specify the TargetPath?
4. Or in other words What do i have to do to remove the cause for the warning?

Comment: At first, I though there may some wrong with the folder, so I created a web project in my side with the same structure, but everything worked fine. Could you pls open your project with VS 2022 and test again?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same warnings but resolved them by running `dotnet clean`